# How do I search for a page's posts with the Graph API?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

What I have:

- The ID of a Facebook page.
- A search string.

What I need returned:

- A list of the URLs or identifiers of posts that match the search string.

I am looking for a particular parameter combination that will work for any Facebook page. What is the form of such a URL? Will it work in the Graph Explorer?

Answer (score 0):

There is no post search. You can only go through all posts on the page (page-id/feed) and search for the string on your own.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.6/page/feed

Comment: How? Can you give me a string that I can use in the Explorer?

Comment: i added a link to the docs to my answer. there is example code for several languages. again, the searching part is up to you, you need to program that after getting the posts.